# bootstrap 3 collapsable not working

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a rails app with bootstrap 3, and the menu is not collapsing. Also when I resize sometimes the three bars show up for the collapse menu but the normal menu items are still there just squeezed together next to it. Here is the haml thanks in advance.

```
%nav.navbar.navbar-inverse{role: 'navigation' }
    %div.container-fluid
      %div.navbar-header
        %button.navbar-toggle{type: 'button', 'data-toggle' => 'collapse', id: 'menu-toggler', 'data-target' => '.navbar-collapse'}
          %span.icon-bar
          %span.icon-bar
          %span.icon-bar
        = link_to (image_tag 'logo.png', class: 'logo'), root_path, class: 'navbar-brand', 'data-no-turbolink' => true
      %div.collapse.navbar-collapse
        %ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
          %li.active= link_to '<i class="icon-dashboard"></i> Dashboard'.html_safe, root_path, 'data-no-turbolink' => true
          %li= link_to '<i class="icon-signout"></i> Logout'.html_safe, destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
          %li= link_to '<i class="icon-envelope"></i> Contact Us'.html_safe, new_contact_request_path
          %li.dropdown
            %a.dropdown-toggle{href: '#', 'data-toggle' => 'dropdown'}
              %i.icon-gears
              Profile
              %b.caret
            %ul.dropdown-menu
              %li= link_to 'Manage email addresses', emails_path
              %li= link_to 'Edit Account', edit_user_registration_path
              %li= link_to 'Setup Wizard', setup_wizard_home_index_path
              %li= link_to 'Cancel Account', cancel_account_home_index_path
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the bootstrap docs I ended up doing this. To get the drop down toggle to work. Still not sure why some of the menu will remain at a certain size and the dropdown option will show up along side.

```
$('#nav-toggle').click(function(){
    $('.collapse').collapse({ toggle: false })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `//= require bootstrap` to your javascript manifest?

Comment: Yes all the necessary CSS and JS are preset.